# Loading Postgres layer with Session parameter (SET) using Pyqgis

Tags: python, pyqgis, postgresql, connection

With postgreSQL 9.5 and +, there is a [policy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createpolicy.html) feature that handle row-level access which is great.

My special case is to use this feature to control access to a multi-user postgres DB.

Here is what i'm trying to do:

I have a postgres table (let's say `test_data`) with a policy associated. The policy is defined as follows:

```
CREATE POLICY test_data_pol ON test_data FOR ALL USING ('conc' = get_pol())
```

`conc` is a column in test_data which contains integer representing id of user that have access to this row of data.
`get_pol()` is a postgres function that retrieve the value of a session parameter (`my.foo`) set by another function `set_pol()` as follow:

**set_pol()**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.set_pol(foo_val integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('SET SESSION my.foo TO %I', foo_val) ;
END;
$BODY$
```

**get_pol()**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_pol()
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  foo_val character varying;
BEGIN
  SHOW my.foo INTO foo_val;
  RETURN foo_val;
END;
$BODY$
```

With that system I can handle the access to the row by executing a `SELECT set_pol(value)` when I connect to the DB. After setting this Session parameter I can access only the relevant rows.

This works well with psycopg2. for example:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host=DATABASE['host'],
                        database=DATABASE['dbname'],
                        user=DATABASE['user'],
                        password=DATABASE['password'],
                        port=DATABASE['port'])
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT set_pol(%s)" % conc_value)
cursor.execute("""SELECT * from test_data""")
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

With that python snippet `data` only contains the row that are accessible with the relevant `conc_value`.

Now I try to add VectorLayer in QGIS using pyqgis with this code snippet:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection(host,
                   port,
                   dbname,
                   user,
                   pasword)
uri.setParam('my.foo', 'conc_value')
uri.setDataSource('public', 'test_data', None, None, 'id')
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'test_data', 'postgres')
```

But the `setParam` statement does not create the variable as expected in the connection Session and I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "my.foo"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SHOW my.foo"
PL/pgSQL function get_pol() line 5 at SQL statement
.
SQL : SELECT * FROM "public"."test_data" LIMIT 1
```

which make me think that the `setParam` function does not do what I need... I need to execute an `SET SESSION my.foo TO 'conc_value'` but setParam doesn't seems to  create the variable the proper way as `SHOW my.foo` in get_pol() raise an error that it does not know the my.foo parameter...

So my question is:

How can I create the connection with pyqgis to handle the creation of `my.foo` parameter at the session level?

OR

How can I modify my `get_pol()` function to be able to access to the `my.foo` parameter create by the `QgsDataSourceURI.setParam()` pyqgis function?